# How can I create and animate 2D skeletons for HTML5 Javascript games?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5, html-canvas, skeletal-animation

I'm trying to make a 2D fighting game in HTML5(somewhat like street fighter). So basically there are two players, one AI and one Human. The players need to have animations for the body movements. Also, there needs to be some collision detection system. I'm using createjs for coding but to design models/objects/animations, I need some other software.

So I'm looking for a software that can:

1. easily make custom animation of 2d objects. The objects
   structure(skeleton etc.) will be same once defined but need to be
   defined once.
2. Can export the animations and models in a js readable
       format(preferably json)

   Collision detection can be done easily after
   the exported format is loaded in a game engine.

For point 1, I'm looking for some generic skeleton based animation. Sprite-sheet based animations will be difficult for collision detection.

Comment: So far you've had all your close votes because you are asking about what tech to use, and that's off-topic for this site.  But you clearly have questions about the very nature of what you're trying to accomplish ("spritesheets are difficult for collision detection" is nonsense).  You should revise your question to ask about the skeleton system you are trying to make, rather than about tech that generates data to be fed into one.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like [Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/spine-runtimes/). Spine is a great tool that recently received a round of funding with a bunch of generic run times that does exactly what you want. ([Yes, there is a Javascript one.)](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/tree/master/spine-js) Everything you need is available in Spine, just keep in mind:

- It's not free - it's 75$ but well worth the price if you'll be doing a lot of these.
- The software isn't fully mature at the time of writing - but it's definitely progressing very quick.

Answer (score 0):

I personally suggest you use a free 3d Software and work with dummy boxes for the different parts.

There are two software (packages) i can think of

- blender (free, also for comercial stuff)

  can export to various formats, i dunno about animation stuff but it should be possible to read it out and export it with a python script
- houdini (free for no ncomercial usage)

  is extremly powerful, you can use python scripts for animation data readout (or read the position and write it into a file)

  can also export to various formats